# Gatsby.js blog is appending '/blog' twice to a post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blogs

I have an index route with a view posts link. On the posts page the posts are all showing the title links but using the netflify CMS today when I was writing another blog post I noticed now the posts page shows the individual post links to localhost:8000/blog/blog/{the-post-name}. If I remove one of the 'blog' parts from the url the associated post loads correctly. I just do not understand why this is occurring as the site was working fine earlier.

The issue seems to be related to {node.fields.slug} incorrectly linking

Any help is appreciated!

gatsby-config

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    // edit below
    title: `Front-end Developer`,
    author: `Alex Virdee`,
    description: `A starter personal blog with styled components, dark mode, and Netlify CMS.`,
    siteUrl: `https://hungry-bassi-27b875.netlify.app/`,
    social: {
      twitter: `alex_virdee`,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-feed-mdx`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/blog`,
        name: `blog`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/assets`,
        name: `assets`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `img`,
        path: `${__dirname}/static`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [".mdx", ".md"],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 590,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
            options: {
              wrapperStyle: `margin-bottom: 1.0725rem`,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-vscode`,
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files`,
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-smartypants`,
          },
        ],
        plugins: [`gatsby-remark-images`],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
      options: {
        // edit below
        // trackingId: `ADD YOUR TRACKING ID HERE`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Gatsby Starter Blog`,
        short_name: `GatsbyJS`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#ffffff`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        // edit below
        icon: `content/assets/gatsby-icon.png`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

gatsby-node

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const blogPost = path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`)
  return graphql(
    `
      {
        allMdx(
          sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
          limit: 1000
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              fields {
                slug
              }
              frontmatter {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  ).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      throw result.errors
    }

    // Create blog posts pages.
    const posts = result.data.allMdx.edges

    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      const previous = index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].node
      const next = index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].node

      createPage({
        path: `blog${post.node.fields.slug}`,
        component: blogPost,
        context: {
          slug: post.node.fields.slug,
          previous,
          next,
        },
      })
    })

    return null
  })
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}
```

layout.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import styled from "styled-components"

import { rhythm, scale } from "../utils/typography"

class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { location, title, children } = this.props
    const rootPath = `${__PATH_PREFIX__}/`
    const blogPath = `${__PATH_PREFIX__}/blog/`
    let header

    if (location.pathname === rootPath || location.pathname === blogPath) {
      header = (
        <h1
          style={{
            ...scale(1.4),
            marginBottom: rhythm(1.2),
            marginTop: 0,
          }}
        >
          <Link
            style={{
              boxShadow: `none`,
              textDecoration: `none`,
              color: `inherit`,
            }}
            to={location.pathname === blogPath ? `/blog/` : `/`}
          >
            {title}
          </Link>
        </h1>
      )
    } else {
      header = (
        <h3
          style={{
            fontFamily: `Montserrat, sans-serif`,
            marginTop: 0,
          }}
        >
          <Link
            style={{
              boxShadow: `none`,
              textDecoration: `none`,
              color: `inherit`,
            }}
            to={`/blog/`}
          >
            {title}
          </Link>
        </h3>
      )
    }
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <div
          style={{
            marginLeft: `auto`,
            marginRight: `auto`,
            maxWidth: rhythm(24),
            padding: `${rhythm(1.5)} ${rhythm(3 / 4)}`,
          }}
        >
          <header>{header}</header>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </div>
        <Footer>
          Built by
          {` `}
         Alex Virdee  © {new Date().getFullYear()}

        </Footer>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  min-height: 100vh;
`

const Footer = styled.footer`
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px;
`

export default Layout
```

Blog page that shows the links to individual posts

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"

import Bio from "../components/bio"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import { rhythm } from "../utils/typography"
import Button from "../components/button"

class Blog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props
    const siteTitle = data.site.siteMetadata.title
    const posts = data.allMdx.edges

    return (
      <Layout location={this.props.location} title={siteTitle}>
        <SEO title="All posts" />
        <Bio />
        <div style={{ margin: "20px 0 40px" }}>
          {posts.map(({ node }) => {
            const title = node.frontmatter.title || node.fields.slug
            return (
              <div key={node.fields.slug}>
                <h3
                  style={{
                    marginBottom: rhythm(1 / 4),
                  }}
                >
                  <Link
                    style={{ boxShadow: `none` }}
                    to={`blog${node.fields.slug}`}
                  >
                    {title}
                  </Link>
                </h3>
                <small>{node.frontmatter.date}</small>
                <p
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: node.frontmatter.description || node.excerpt,
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
        <Link to="/">
          <Button marginTop="15px">Go Home</Button>
        </Link>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default Blog

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    allMdx(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            title
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Could you post your code in the question instead of a link to the code? That way we have a record of the state of the code at the time of your question, and if the URL becomes invalid the question could still be helpful to others.

Comment: Updated post to show the config and posts page code! Hopefully will be able to solve this soon.

Comment: It's not because of the `blog` prefix in `createPage`'s `path`?

Comment: I removed the ```blog``` prefix in createPage and added a new post. That one still goes to 'http://localhost:8000/blog/blog/no-prefix'

Comment: Hm, maybe dump the slug and see what it is. The `<Link>` tag also includes a `blog` prefix, and your `blogPath` var does as well.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response @DaveNewton. Removed slug and blog prefix from Link tags and now everythings good. '/blog' page it now links to 'localhost:8000/{blog-post-name}' which is fine. Wonder how it changed to begin with but thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `Blog` class you need a `/` in your `<Link>` component at `to={blog${node.fields.slug}}`

So `{/blog${node.fields.slug}}`

Without that it'll take the relative path

(I've left out the backticks inside the outer curly braces as it mucks up the formatting on stack overflow, but they should still be there)

Answer (score 0):

```
`const StyledIconButton = styled(IconButton)`
width:56px;
height:56px;
```

``
This was my mistake. I was trying to style MUi IconButton Component.
You might also mistaking somewhere.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.